# Address Extraction from text in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nlp

I am working on a Business Card reader app which has some extra features other than business card reading. Presently, I am stuck in address extraction process. The addresses I am working on are not of any specific country. They are global addresses. 
The app is meant to run offline. So, I can't consume any online API to detect the address. I have gone trough several blogs and tried to implement most of them but with no effect. I tried with several regular expressions as well but nothing seemed to work so far. I have some Business Card reader apps installed in my mobile which detect the addresses beautifully. I need a logic which can extract address from an unstructured text.

Comment: Are you trying to extract the address from an image of the business card?

Comment: `NSDataDetector`. See: [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/). Just reading blogs does not substitute for studying the APIs.

Comment: Yes. I am using tesseract to extract the text from image.

Comment: Thanks Zaph, I'll try to implement that.

Comment: @Zaph `NSDataDetector` didn't work for me. Seems like Apple has concentrated in US addresses only. The Indian addresses were not at all detected. Sample address would be: "100-B, 12th Floor, Westend Marg \n Saidulajaib, New Delhi-110040"